# angular2 structural directive with String as input

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to create a structural directive with the example given 
[here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html)

Just with a modification to pass string as a Input here, I got 'undefined' as input value while calling this directive form markup.

```
@Input() set myUnless(value: String) {
    if (value=== 'something') {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
```

Any help to achieve this?

**Edit:** 
Idea is to create a hasRole directive which accept a Role as String and return boolean on the basis of if this found in roles stored in local storage.

Implementation code is:

```
 <a routerLink="/list" *unless="ADMIN">
          <i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span>List</span>
 </a>
```

and code for directive is like:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[unless]' })
export class Unless {
    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ) { }
    @Input() set unless(role: String) {
        return localStorage.getItem('roles').indexOf(role) > -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: Please show the code how you use the directive.

Comment: Editted to add code to show implementation and use of directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `ADMIN` of your component is actually `undefined` ;-)

Use instead

```
*unless="'ADMIN'"
```

Comment: Thank You solution worked :) 
It was a silly mistake.

Comment: ... but happens a lot